# Making a foam and dissolving it

Tags: sauce, molecular-gastronomy, presentation, foam

I saw a TV show where a dish was served covered with a foam and subsequently a sauce was poured over the foam, which dissolved to reveal the dish under the foam. I have tried dissolving regular lecithin aire foams with vinegar, salt etc. without success.

Any suggestion for a combination of a stable foam and a sauce which readily dissolves the foam?

Comment: What TV show?  Knowing where you saw this might help others to determine what kind of foam it was, and what the "dissolving agent" was.

Comment: You say 'stable foam' but if it dissolved so easily it may have been made just prior to service for a showy effect.

Comment: @Xander - The TV show was a Danish competition - perhaps qualification for Bocuse d'Or around 2010.

Comment: @dbmag9 - I think you are right; stable was just my was of saying serving with a foam, which stayed as foam for several minutes. But I wonder if some additive will work as defoaming agent, to speed up unstability